# I am beginner in assembly language programming, unable to find out negative numbers in given array

Tags: arrays, assembly, masm

Question regarding Assembly Language Programming (using Masm Irvine32 Library).

I am trying to check and count negative numbers in the given array:

```
arrayW:  3, -2, 5, 7, 2, 9, -11, 32, -19, 18, 17, 15, -5, 2, 3, 1, -21, 27,-29, 20,
```

In the output the number that is displayed will be 6 because there are 6 negative elements in arrayW, namely:

```
 -2, -11, -19, -5, -21, -29.
```

Here I have tried a code which is calculating numbers between (-2, 17) in the given array, but unable to understand how to code to check and count negative elements is given array, can anyone please help me here

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.DATA
arrayW SDWORD 3, -2, 5, 7, 2, 9, -11, 32, -19, 18, 17, 15, -5, 2, 3, 1, -21, 27,-29, 20
initVal SDWORD -2
finalVal SDWORD 17
finalCount SDWORD ?

.CODE
between PROC
cmp eax,ebx                 
jg next3                    ; if eax>ebx, 0<-EAX
cmp ebx,ecx
jg next3                    ; if ebx>ecx, 0<-EAX
mov eax,1                   ; 1 in EAX register if eax<=ebx and ebx<=eax
jmp next4
next3:
mov eax,0                   ; if (eax<=ebx and ebx<=ecx) evaluates to false, 
then 0<-EAX
next4:
;call DumpRegs              ;Display the register contents
ret
between ENDP
main PROC
mov edi, 0
mov ecx, LENGTHOF arrayW
mov edx,0                   ;EDX will hold the count of the elements in the array in the range [-2,17]
L1:
push ecx                    ;push the contents of counter register ecx to 
stack

mov eax, initVal            ;the element in the array should be <= -2
mov ebx,arrayW[edi]         ;move the element in the array to ebx
mov ecx, finalVal           ;the element in the array should be <= 17
call between                ;between proc call 
add edx,eax                 ;if the element is in the range [-2,17], add 1 to 
EDX
add edi,TYPE arrayW         ;add 4 to edi to move to the next element
pop ecx                     ;pop the value of counter register 
loop L1                     ;repeat the above for all the elements in the 
array (until ecx is 0)
mov eax,edx                 ;Move the count to eax register
call WriteInt               ;To display the output in decimal format
;call DumpRegs              ;Display the register contents              

exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be more efficient ways, but one possible solution would be to replace `call between` / `add edx,eax` with this:

```
bt ebx,31   ; CF = (ebx < 0) ? 1 : 0
adc edx,0   ; edx += CF
```

Comment: I'd go with `shr ebx, 31` (extract sign bit to a 0/1 integer) / `add edx, ebx`

Comment: Or avoid a separate `mov` load with `cmp arrayW[edi], 0x7fffffff` / `sbb edx, -1`, but that's less efficient on Intel before Broadwell, because the adc-with-immediate-0 single uop special case doesn't apply.  (Or with the max positive integer in another register, you could `cmp ebx, arrayW[edi]` / `adc edx, 0` to set CF = MSB of the memory operand, instead of the inverse.)

Comment: Thankyou, I am trying to determine the number of negative and positive numbers in an array in assembler. It seems that the assembler doesn't recognizes them as negative numbers. How can I solve this problem? I define the array this way: arrayW SDWORD 3, -2, 5, 7, 2, 9, -11, 32, -19, 18, 17, 15, -5, 2, 3, 1, -21, 27,-29, 20 using Masm32 Irvine Library